# Is there an equivalent class/API in Solr like IndexingOperationListener in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, search-engine

I need to capture Create/Index/Delete events in Solr and I understand that it is possible by using IndexingOperationListener in elasticsearch. Is there an equivalent of the same in Solr? There is SolrEventListener, but I am not able to get information whether SolrEventListener would provide Create/Index/Delete notifications as it is not clear from all the sources I've tried.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-EventListeners) is the nearest. The idea is to add an event listener for each handler. We have separate handlers for each opedartion like query, update, delete in solr.